# Files missing when connecting iPad to Windows 10

Tags: ipad, video, graphics, storage

When I connect my iPad to my Windows 10 computer, it shows the device "iPad" with the "Internal Storage" as a folder. This storage contains three folders with a couple of pictures and videos I took with my iPad, but it doesn't show *all* of the pictures and videos - some are missing. How can I view/access all the pictures and videos on my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Install iTunes on your PC and connect your iPad. When iTunes launches and sees the iPad, click on the iPad icon at the top of the window to the right of the "music, movies TV Shows" icons.

Click on "Summary" on the left and you can select the options you want (apps, music, movies, pictures) to sync your media and where you want them copied to. Note that you have to have the iPad connected and selected in iTunes to make these changes.

Apple has set up IOS devices so only a limited amount of data is exposed to Windows Explorer. Why you are only seeing some of them, I am not sure, but once you set up Sync iTunes will copy all new pictures and videos to your PC.